# Show that a class of holomorphic functions is a normal family.

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

Let $F$ be the class of all holomorphic functions on the unit disc $D$ satisfying
$$\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta\le1$$
for each $r$ in $(0,1)$.
Prove that $F$ is a normal family in the unit disc $D$.

I have a hint : use Montel's theorem (If $F$ is bounded by for each cpt subset $K$ of $D$, then $F$ is a normal family in $D$)

I tried to show that $F$ is bounded directly, or start with an assumption that $F$ is not bounded in some compact subset to derive a contradiction. But they are not successful.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bound $f$ on the closed ball centered at $0$ and radius $R$, pick $r\in (R,1)$ and use [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) where $\gamma$ is the circle centered at the origin and with radius $r$.

Comment: Is this equivalent to the statement " $|f|$ does not exceed the mean value of $|f|$ on a small disc centered at 0"?